# Rust String from temporary u8 slice

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to run a command and capture its output.

```
let result = match Command::new(thing.command).output() {
            Ok(out) => String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stdout),
            Err(_) => ....,
        };
```

I get the error for `&out.stdout` that `borrowed value does not live long enough`. I understand the issue, but how can I create a copy of the u8 slice and transfer complete ownership into a newly created string?

Comment: That's probably because [`String::from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) returns a `Cow` object, not `String`, if you don't really care about slight decrease in performance due to 1 unnecessary copy of string data, then the simplest workaround is `String::from_utf8_lossy(&out.stdout).into_owned()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from_utf8_lossy`'s return value is a `Cow`:

`pub fn from_utf8_lossy(v: &[u8]) -> Cow<'_, str>`

If you want to create a copy and transfer the ownership, `into_owned()` of `Cow` is specifically designed for that:

```
pub fn into_owned(self) -> <B as ToOwned>::Owned
Extracts the owned data.

Clones the data if it is not already owned.
```